# How to make redirect_url containing data to oauth Google

Tags: cors, google-oauth, axios

I'm having a little hard times to implement authentication flow.

This following flow is working :
Fromclient side, I'm doing a redirect to serv side :

```
document.location.href = URI.UriSignIn
```

On serv side, I'm doing a redirect to Google's authorization server :

```
const baseURI = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?";
  const redirect_uri =
    `redirect_uri=http://${process.env.URIBASE}:8081/callBackGoogle`;
  const prompt = "&prompt=consent";
  const reponse_type = "&response_type=code";
  const client_id =
    "&client_id=" + process.env.CLIENT_ID;
  const scope =
    "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";

  res.writeHead(302, {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    Location:
      baseURI +
      redirect_uri +
      prompt +
      reponse_type +
      client_id +
      scope
  });
```

It's working but now I'm trying to add "UUID" to the redirect from client side to server side so the client can retrieve his JWT later like this :

```
axios.get(URI.UriSignIn, {
    headers: {
        'token-client': uuid()
    }
})
```

with the same code serv side and I get the following error
[image: error]
[image: detail]

I have find a workaround that is split the redirect in 2 requests, one to send the UUID and the other to redirect but that is not the safest thing to do (security reasons)

Comment: axios.get isn't a redirect, it's an ajax call. Look at using  the `state` parameter, maybe that will help you.

Comment: Yeah, I know but that is precisely why I want to send UUID to the server so it can use the UUID in the "state" parameter to send to Google's authorization server. And later after JWT is created the client can retrieve by sending this specific UUID

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226416

Comment: Plus I want to send data to the server (maybe should I use POST?) and from server side, it will make the redirection to Google's authorization server

Comment: make sure you are clear which URLs are REST endpoints and which are browser URLs. You can set `state=uuid` in the browser URL to your server, your server can parse that URL and then re-use it as the state param in the OAuth URL.

Comment: I've posted the answer to your question. I suggest if you have further questions, like "how do I ....?" you should post that as a new question. This helps keep SO tidy and useful for future devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question as asked is that OP is using an ajax/rest call to a URL which should be the target of a redirect.

So, in broad terms, instead of

> axios.get(url)

user should do

> location.href=url

Comment: location.href=url + '/uuid' is working like a charm, another alternative is just using cookie or session (cookie should be enough) so everything is manage server side

Comment: Cool. Be careful about relying on sessions. REST is stateless and there may come a time when your app grows and you move it onto a multi-server configuration. This is why Google OAuth provides the `state` param.